# Wrapping JTextArea does not get enough space / steals space

Tags: java, swing

It appears a wrapping (`setLineWrap(true)`)  `JTextArea` does not get enough space and is therefore cut off:
[image: JTextArea cut off]

Making the parent layout out its children twice appears to solve this problem:
[image: JTextArea proper size]

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JTextAreaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            Arrays.asList(true, false).forEach(packTwice -> {
                testWrappingCutOff(packTwice);
            });
        });
    }
      
    private static void testWrappingCutOff(boolean packTwice) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("packTwice: " + packTwice);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JTextArea wrapping = new JTextArea();
        wrapping.setLineWrap(true);
        wrapping.setText(Collections.nCopies(10, "wrapping").stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        frame.add(wrapping);

        frame.pack();
        // Second call to pack() solves the problem
        if (packTwice) {
            frame.pack();
        }
        
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Additionally when it is used together with other components, it "steals" space from them. I.e. when the other components are inside a `JScrollPane`, they get scrollbars even though their common parent component could just be enlarged to fit both components:
[image: JTextArea stealing space]

Calling `pack()` twice solves this problem again:
[image: Both components properly layed out]

Laying out the parent twice is rather inconvenient and might not always be possible.

- Am I using the class incorrectly?
- Is this is known limitation, because wrapping can only happen once it is known how much space is available?
- Is this a (not yet reported) bug with Swing?
- Or is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing components determine there own preferred size. This is generally done by doing something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

so the text area can size itself to display 5 rows of data and 20 "W" characters. Typically a JTextArea is then added to a JScrollPane to scrollbars will appear if needed.

However, I'm guessing this is not really what you want. You are attempting to have the text fit completely into a JTextArea. The problem is the text area doesn't know how to calculate its own preferred size because it doesn't know what width to use for the text area.

The first pack() will result in the width of the frame being the width of the title bar components, which means the text area will be sized to fill the width of the content pane. For the second pack() the text area can now calculate its preferred height, knowing its current width.

You can prevent the need for the second pack() by providing a hint to the text area by using something like:

```
wrapping.setSize(200, 1);
```

Now the text area is sized after the first pack().

Comment: Ideally I would not want to set a fixed size or have to calculate the size myself. It would be better if the layout manager could do this, but apparently this is not possible here.